# Find two functions f,g such that $f(n)∼g(n)$ and $f(n)^n=o(g(n)^n)$

Tags: limits, algorithms, asymptotics

I am trying to find two functions $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ such that $f(n) ∼ g(n)$ and $f(n)^n=o(g(n)^n)$ where $f,g > 1$.

I tried it to solve it by using $\lim$ formula but unable to get $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ satisfied by both of them. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $f,g$ to be functions that go to $1$ at different speeds, e.g. $f(n)=1+\frac{1}{n}, g(n)=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. Then it is clear that $f\sim g$, but $f(n)^n\to e$ and $g(n)^n\to\infty$, so $f(n)^n=o(g(n)^n)$.